Offline map in Power BI
How to use an offline map (with lat and long) in Power BI?
I need to use maps without internet connection.
I have trieed Shape Map, Filled map, and and OKViz but they are not a solution for a map containing latitude / longitude, like Azure.

They all use an api or service to generate the map, there isn’t an offline version

try Mapbox Studio or ArcGIS they used to work for me
